# Highcharts Pie Chart: How to ignore disabled legend items

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

Please see this [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/t13jymwk/).

In this example, you can see sum of all values at top left corner.

If you click on any legend item, it will be disabled, but the total value doesn't reflect it. The text should be updated to not include that disabled item. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `legendItemClick` event to update the rendered text by keeping a reference to the `Element`. For example:

```
var totalText;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                totalText = this.renderer.text(
                    'Total: ' + total,
                    this.plotLeft,
                    this.plotTop - 20
                ).attr({
                    zIndex: 5
                }).add()
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function(e) {
                        var newTotal = this.series.total + (this.visible ? -this.y : this.y);
                        totalText.attr({ text: 'Total: '+newTotal });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t13jymwk/26/) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

While Ondkloss's answer works fine. But I have found a simpler solution, by using redraw event instead of load. [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/rhgq6cgg/1/)